# COM client's C++ class inherits COM server's class interface, uses RAII

Tags: c#, c++, com, atl

<s>I have this ATL COM server which is built in VS2017 C++ and properly registered, and client side in C++, also built with same tool.</s>

*Now this COM server is actually built in C#*

<s>Client side can register a callback function, but to do that it must implement INotificationListener COM interface which is of course defined and registered.
Just wondering if one can simply inherit from COM interface class, implement all necessary abstract functions and use regular C++ RAII?</s>

*Previously when COM server was in C++, this worked by accident it seems. When we used new COM server in C#, this blew up in C++ COM client. Hence, I switched to a different method to create listener.*

<s>I will put a COM client code snippet which worked, but I'm having doubts whether this is the right and/or correct way to go.</s>

*Code snippet below corrected, no longer user plain C++ class RAII instantiation, but rather uses COM/ATL method. Regular C++ RAII did not work if COM server is C#*

```
class SomeNotificationListener : public INotificationListener
{
public:
SomeNotificationListener()
: m_nRefCount(0)
{
}

virtual ~SomeNotificationListener()
{
}

// IUnknown abstract function implementation
// now that COM server is in C# and we use ATL/COM to
// create INotificationListener object,
// this function gets called many times
// the trick to make it work was to reject unknown interfaces by
// returning E_NOINTERFACE
HRESULT __stdcall QueryInterface(const IID &riid, void **ppObj) override
{
    if (riid == __uuidof(INotificationListener))
    {
        *ppObj = static_cast<INotificationListener*>(this);
        AddRef();
    }
    else if (riid == IID_IUnknown)
    {
        *ppObj = static_cast<IUnknown*>(this);
        AddRef();
    }
    else
    {
        *ppObj = nullptr;
        return E_NOINTERFACE;
    }


    return S_OK;
}

// IUnknown abstract function implementation
// never gets called
ULONG __stdcall AddRef(void) override
{
    return InterlockedIncrement(&m_nRefCount);
}

// IUnknown abstract function implementation
// never gets called (good as this code which calls "delete this" would
// cause undefined behavior if combined with RAII
// this is copied from some COM samples
// typical Release() implementation
ULONG __stdcall Release(void) override
{
    long nRefCount = 0;
    nRefCount = InterlockedDecrement(&m_nRefCount);

    // this part also created problems if COM server was in C#
    // 'delete this' very dangerous and not the way to go if you use
    // ATL/COM smart pointers
    //if (0 == nRefCount)
    //    delete this;

    return nRefCount;
}


// this is the function that is used by COM server to notify client
// INotificationListener abstract function implementation
// it DOES get called

HRESULT __stdcall Notify(
/*[in]*/ unsigned long dwCount,
/*[in]*/ BSTR * psAddresses,
/*[in]*/ VARIANT * pvarValues,
/*[in]*/ DATE * pdtTimestamps) override
{
   // just stub code here
   // setting a break point on next line does work
   return S_OK;
}


private:
   long m_nRefCount;
};


int main()
{
HRESULT hr = CoInitialize(NULL);

// open context
// upon closing curly brace, all COM smart pointers will be freed
{
   // here's our listener object on client side
   // after some experiments, it seemed the best to create using COM smartptr
   INotificationListener fnListener(new SomeNotificationListener());

    auto uid = __uuidof(SomeRequestFactory);

    IRequestFactoryPtr rfPtr(uid);

    // notification request from COM server
    auto notify = rfPtr->CreateNotificationRequest();

    // here client registers listener
    // fnListener is COM smartptr
    notify->SetListener(fnListener);

    // COM server's Subscribe will call Notify()
    // on INotificationListener interface
    // since SomeNotificationListener implements all abstract functions
    // from INotificationListener, Notify() does indeed get called
    notify->Subscribe();

// all COM smart ptrs cleared
}

CoUninitialize();

return 0;
}
```

Now this seems to work correctly. Still some doubts over QueryInterface correctness, but much better than before.

Comment: COM does not stricly require registration. At its simplest form, it's "just" a binary layout format based on IUnkown and vtables. For example, DirectX uses COM just like this, in a lightweight fashion. However if you go down that route, it also means you won't benefit from additional COM services (like crossthread/crossprocess marshaling, registration services, runtime type metadata/TLB, threading synchronization, etc.) It also depends if you are going to distribute your code or keep it for you.

Comment: You cannot ignore this behavior.  It might not necessarily be fatal to your wrapper class but the delayed Release() call is also the one that causes the RequestFactory object to get its final Release call.  You can't generally know whether it deals with CoUninitialize() having been called.  Even if it doesn't blow up, it is likely you lost the ability to do memory leak checks reliably.  The solution is to also wrap the un/initialization in a C++ wrapper, call CoInitialize in the constructor and CoUninitialize in the destructor.

Comment: My previous comment entry is wrong, hence I deleted it. Got it running cleanly in the end. Thanks for pointers Hans and Simon.